# Javascript fetch API doesn't return

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm running an HTTP server with python -m http.server that's serving my ressources.
Here's my layout :

```
dist/
   bundle.js
   index.html
   style.css
assets/
   tracks/
       listing.json
```

I have the following code :

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/assets/tracks/listing.json")
    .then(() => console.log("Got it"))
```

So far so good, it prints 'Got it' after a few ms.
But when I do that :

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/assets/tracks/listing.json")
    .then(() => console.log("Got it"))

while (true) {}
```

It just somehow freezes without printing anything, and the page has that little blue circle indicating it's still loading.

I have a way of not using that while loop, and, so to say, to solve the problem.
But I think this has something to do with how asynchronous processes work in Javascript, and I think it could be good for me to learn a bit more about exactly why it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: That `while()` loop totally blocks all other activity in the browser. I suggest not doing that.

Comment: You can read how the JavaScript Event Loop works, everything will be clear. Don't forget that JavaScript is single-threaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See also: [*What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does most of its processing on *the main [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)*.

While the `while` loop is running, the main event loop is occupied with that piece of code.

It isn't free to pick up queued tasks (like your `then` callback).

The `while` loop **prevents JS from doing anything else**. Never use an infinite loop.

Comment: Is there anything like DoEvents or nope statement that can help to do other tasks while in an infinit loop?

Comment: @sairfan - No, there isn't, and there won't be. JavaScript guarantees run-to-completion semantics for jobs picked up from the job queue. More in [Section 9.5 of the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-jobs).